# Call WorkManagerImpl.getInstance in background.systemjob.SystemJobService.onCreate caused java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-workmanager

We are using the following WorkManager library

```
def work_version = "2.1.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

---

Our `Application` class is being modified as follow so that it will work well with `WorkManager`

```
public class WeNoteApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements DefaultLifecycleObserver, Configuration.Provider {

    private static WeNoteApplication me;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        me = this;

        ...
    }

   public static WeNoteApplication instance() {
        return me;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return new Configuration.Builder()
                .build();
    }
}
```

---

We do not add any `WorkManager` related code in `AndroidManifest.xml`. We solely rely on [Default initialization](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#default)

---

This is how we construct `WorkManager`

```
public static WorkManager getWorkManager() {
    WeNoteApplication weNoteApplication = WeNoteApplication.instance();
    return WorkManager.getInstance(weNoteApplication);
}
```

The above function is called in 4 different places

1. `Activity`
2. `Fragment`
3. `BroadcastReceiver`
4. `IntentService`

---

Still, we receive the following crash log in production. It happens in Android 7.1, Android 8.1, Android 9 (so far)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:3265)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1598)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6274)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance (WorkManagerImpl.java:142)
  at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService.onCreate (SystemJobService.java:53)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:3255)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1598)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6274)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

As you can see in the crash, the crash origins from `WorkManager` internally, and not from our app.

By looking at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/WorkManagerImpl.java#142

### WorkManagerImpl

```
/**
 * Retrieves the singleton instance of {@link WorkManagerImpl}.
 *
 * @param context A context for on-demand initialization.
 * @return The singleton instance of {@link WorkManagerImpl}
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
public static @NonNull WorkManagerImpl getInstance(@NonNull Context context) {
    synchronized (sLock) {
        WorkManagerImpl instance = getInstance();
        if (instance == null) {
            Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
            if (appContext instanceof Configuration.Provider) {
                initialize(
                        appContext,
                        ((Configuration.Provider) appContext).getWorkManagerConfiguration());
                instance = getInstance(appContext);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You "
                        + "have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, "
                        + "have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and "
                        + "your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.");
            }
```

There are 2 possibilities of `IllegalStateException`

1. `appContext` is null. (How can it be null?)
2. `appContext` does not implement `Configuration.Provider` (But we already implement `Configuration.Provider` in our `WeNoteApplication`?)

To figure out how context is being passed to `WorkManagerImpl` from `SystemJobService`, we look at the code of 
`androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService.onCreate` - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/background/systemjob/SystemJobService.java#53

### SystemJobService

```
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
@RequiresApi(WorkManagerImpl.MIN_JOB_SCHEDULER_API_LEVEL)
public class SystemJobService extends JobService implements ExecutionListener {
    private static final String TAG = Logger.tagWithPrefix("SystemJobService");
    private WorkManagerImpl mWorkManagerImpl;
    private final Map<String, JobParameters> mJobParameters = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mWorkManagerImpl = WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

---

Look fine at first sight. But, why `WorkManagerImpl` cannot obtain `Configuration.Provider` although I already implement `Configuration.Provider` in my `Application`? Is it because I'm using `MultiDexApplication`?

---

### Finding

In SystemJobService, it can expect null, and able to tolerance null from WorkManagerImpl.getInstance, due to **auto-backup** reason.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mWorkManagerImpl = WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    if (mWorkManagerImpl == null) {
        // This can occur if...
        // 1. The app is performing an auto-backup.  Prior to O, JobScheduler could erroneously
        //    try to send commands to JobService in this state (b/32180780).  Since neither
        //    Application#onCreate nor ContentProviders have run, WorkManager won't be
        //    initialized.  In this case, we should ignore all JobScheduler commands and tell it
        //    to retry.
```

But, current `WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(Context context)` implementation is that, it will never return null but throw `IllegalStateException`.

Isn't there's conflict among these 2 `SystemJobService.onCreate` logic, and `WorkManagerImpl.getInstance` logic?

---

### Issue tracker

I submitted my observation to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135858602

Comment: Can you try to get the message of IllegalStateException because looking at Github code, it made me realize that there are two places from where this exception is thrown therefore getting the exact message from this exception make us identify the root cause better.

Comment: That's all I have. The crash log in Google Play console shows that much of info so far. If you look at my finding, I believe when they introduce WorkManager.getInstance(Context), they didn't handle for edge case b/32180780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. A fix will be available in WorkManager `2.1.0-rc01` later this week.

Comment: I'm using androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4 but still have this issue. Samsung Galaxy Note10 only.